# ¿Cómo puedo implementar este método para para filtrar un array de objetos?

Tags: javascript

Encontré esta implementación que devuelve el arreglo sin elementos primitivos duplicados, pero solo esos, primitivos. Quisiera poder implementarlo para descartar  objetos de un array de acuerdo a un campo.

Esta es la función:

```
const array = ['1', '1', '2', '1'];

Array.prototype.unique = function (a) {
    return function () { return this.filter(a) }
}(function (a, b, c) {
    return c.indexOf(a, b + 1) < 0
});

console.log(array.unique())

/* La salida es: ['1', '2'] */
/* Aunque en otro orden que no me interesa entender */
```

> Más información de la función [aquí](http://www.etnassoft.com/2011/06/24/array-unique-eliminar-valores-duplicados-de-un-array-en-javascript/).

Cómo podría implementarlo si quiero filtrar, por ejemplo, el campo id de los objetos de este arreglo:

```
const objs = [{id: '1', otrasPropiedades: 0}, {id: '1', otrasPropiedades: 0},
{id: '2', otrasPropiedades: 3}]

/*Entonces, si yo le aplico unique() quisiera que devolviera esto:*/

console.log(objs.unique());

/*[{id: '1', otrasPropiedades: 0}, {id: '2', otrasPropiedades: 3}]*/
```

Los objetos con el mismo id son esencialmente iguales en sus propiedades y sus valores.

Comment: No se de donde obtienes los resultados, pero si vienen de una base de datos podrías hacerle un DISTINCT al momento de recaudarlos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres hacerlo similar al ejemplo que pusiste en la pregunta, puedes mapear un array con los valores unicos, en este caso de tu id y filtrar los valores únicos con `indexOf`:

```js
Array.prototype.uniqueByProperty = function (param)  {
    const keys = this.map(el => el[param])
    return this.filter((value, index) => (
        keys.indexOf(
            value[param],
            index + 1
        ) < 0
    ))
};

console.log(
  [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 1}].uniqueByProperty('id')
)
```

de esa manera le envías el nombre de la propiedad para obtener los valores únicos.

Comment: Todos tienen interesantes soluciones y son eficaces, pero esta me parece elegante y similar al de la función, gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Usando `.reduce` e `.includes` lo que podemos lograr es una iteración completa del reduce y las mínimas iteraciones necesarias de `.includes`, ya que este va a devolver `true` en la primera coincidencia y no seguirá iterando.

```js
const objs = [{ id: '1', otrasPropiedades: 0 }, { id: '1', otrasPropiedades: 0 },
{ id: '2', otrasPropiedades: 3 }];


Array.prototype.unique = function () {

    const ids = [];
    return this.reduce((p, c) => {
        if (!ids.includes(c.id)) {
            p.push(c);
            ids.push(c.id);
        }
        return p;
    }, []);
}


console.log(objs.unique());
```

Comment: Linda solución, gracias por compartir.

Answer (score 2):

Hola Te paso el siguiente code, tal vez te sirve

```js
 // suponiendo que el json es valido
milista = 
[
{ "id":"38","product":"harina"},
{ "id":"38","product":"harina"},
{ "id":"38","product":"harina"},
{ "id":"39","product":"azucar"},
{ "id":"40","product":"maicena"},
{ "id":"40","product":"maicena"}
];

// creo otra lista
var listaSinDuplicados = {}

 // recorro -milista- accediendo a la posicion id y guardo el producto ( es 
 // decir el par clave:valor)
 // cuando se lee un id , ingresa al nuevo listado y copia los datos asociados
 for(var i=0; i<milista.length; i++) {
       listaSinDuplicados[milista[i]['id']] = milista[i]['product'];
}

document.write(listaSinDuplicados);
console.log(listaSinDuplicados);
```

Tal vez, no es eficiente porque por cada elemento duplicado, va a sobreescribir la nueva lista

Answer (score 1):

podrías hacerlo asi.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const objs = [{"id": "1", "otrasPropiedades": 0}, {"id": "1", "otrasPropiedades": 0},
{"id": '2', "otrasPropiedades": 3}];

        function eliminarDuplicados(arrayActual, clave) {
             var nuevoArray = [];
             var parabuscar  = {};

             for(var i in arrayActual) {
                parabuscar[arrayActual[i][clave]] = arrayActual[i];
             }
             for(i in parabuscar) {
                 nuevoArray.push(parabuscar[i]);
             }
              return nuevoArray;
        }

        console.log(eliminarDuplicados(objs,"id"));

    </script>
```

Avisame si te funciona como quieres.

Comment: Una explicación de que y como lo resolviste vendría bien, recuerda responder con solo código se considera de baja calidad